# How to push array into array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is result from api

```
[
  {
    "order": 0,
    "section_menu_id": 3
  },
  {
    "order": 1,
    "section_menu_id": 1
  },
]
```

This is initial data

```
{
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": null,
      "section_menu_id": null
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what i am expect

```
{
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": 0,
      "section_menu_id": 3
    },
    {
      "order": 1,
      "section_menu_id": 1
    },
  ]
}
```

Can someone tell me how to make it as the expected result .Thank in advance

Comment: `initial.ordering_data = result;` ?

Comment: Assuming initial data object is in a variable called "initial_data". Then you can update using initial_data.ordering_data = whatever_api_response.
Also, I think you missed closing bracket for arrays in expected output.

Comment: yeah , it worked. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const apiResult = [
  {
    "order": 0,
    "section_menu_id": 3
  },
  {
    "order": 1,
    "section_menu_id": 1
  },
]

const initialData = {
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": null,
      "section_menu_id": null
    }
  ]
}

initalData.ordering_data = apiResult;
```

Comment: yeah , it worked. thankyou

Comment: can you accept the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

check the snippet below. In order to add (push) to the array (instead overwriting the variable value) you should use the JS array push method, like in the snippet:
(otherwise it is just new assignment to the variable)

```js
const res = [
  {
    "order": 0,
    "section_menu_id": 3
  },
  {
    "order": 1,
    "section_menu_id": 1
  }
];

const objContainer = {
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": null,
      "section_menu_id": null
    }
  ]
};

//  objContainer["ordering_data"].splice(0,1); // (uncomment to get the result you wanted)
res.forEach(obj => objContainer.ordering_data.push(obj));
console.log(objContainer)
```